# imagecreatetruecolor() returns corrupted (?) data

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, php-8

I am trying to figure out how GD works in php. When I create a GDImage from a file, I can display it properly but if I try to create the GDImage with `imagecreatetruecolor()` or `imagecreate()`, all I get is a corrupted-like string.

Creating and displaying from a file (properly displays the image):

```
$content = file_get_contents($filePath);
$gdimg = imagecreatefromstring($content);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($gdimg);
imagedestroy($gdimg);
```

Creating from scratch :

```
$dst_w = 50;
$dst_h = 50;
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
```

The latter returns this string :

> ����JFIF``��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default quality ��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��22"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?���(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(���

Comment: I know this is probably a silly question, but what makes you think that result is corrupted? Does it say so in the browser? Have you tried saving it and opening it in any other programs? Also, what values are you setting in `$dst_w` and `$dst_h`?

Comment: @IMSoP I tried to save it to a file and it did not display anything. I think the string is way too short to be a complete file anyway. The two variables contain the integer 50 (I edited the post to show it)

Comment: It's definitely not too short - remember that JPEG is a compressed format, so doesn't have a fixed size per pixel. An area of all one colour is extremely compressible. I just ran that code locally, and successfully generated a 755 byte file, which shows a 50x50 black square, and if viewed in a text editor looks extremely similar to your string. So, your problem just seems to be why you're seeing it as a string and not an image.

Comment: Really ? I don't understand why it wouldn't display as an image using this method while it works using the first though

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? One possibility is that you have some small amount of output somewhere, and are getting a ["Headers already sent" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/157957). Then the browser would try to read the returned data as HTML, and show it to you like that.

Comment: I'll check tomorrow and get back to you then, thank you

Comment: I do not understand why the image won't show on the browser but when I save it to a file it works, so I guess it's all good -_- Thank you for your help

Comment: Open your browser's dev tools (usually by pressing F12) and find the raw network response. My guess is that you will _not_ see the header `Content-Type: image/jpeg` for the "corrupted" image - the server is sending the right _data_, but it is not telling the browser to _interpret_ that data as an image. To find out why _that_ is, you need to find your PHP or web server error logs, which should say why they failed to send that header.

Comment: I checked the logs and nothing was displayed, and yeah the content-type of the response is text/html, but my goal was to save the image to a file and I was only trying to display it for debug

Comment: Well, you definitely have a bug somewhere, which you may have to figure out sooner or later. My money is on "Headers already sent" due to something silly like a "UTF-8 BOM". That would imply that you also have your logging set up incorrectly, which is also going to be an on-going problem.